# Can't test POST $http request with $httpBackend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Trying to cover http requests of my app by unit tests. I use Jasmine and Karma and step by step write my code using this tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend. But I get an error:

```
Error: No pending request to flush !
        at Function.$httpBackend.flush (eval at <anonymous> (app/index.js:105:1), <anonymous>:1839:41)
        at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app/index.js:137:1), <anonymous>:37:20)
```

This answer [Unit testing AngularJS controller with $httpBackend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427968/unit-testing-angularjs-controller-with-httpbackend#16429425) is so popular for my problem but when I move `const controller = createController();` down - I've got another one error: `Error: Unsatisfied requests: POST http://loalhost:5000/register`.

Where is my mistake? What I implemented wrong?

My unit test:

```
beforeEach(window.module(ngModule.name));

let $httpBackend, $rootScope, $controller, $scope, createController;

beforeEach(
  inject($injector => {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createController = () =>
      $controller('RegistrationController', { $scope });
  })
);

afterEach(() => {
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});

it('should successfully register user', () => {
  const controller = createController();
  $httpBackend.flush();
  $httpBackend.expectPOST('http://localhost:5000/register').respond();
  $scope.next('hello@gmail.com', '123456');
  $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Block of code from the controller:

```
  $scope.status;
  $scope.isFetching = false;

  const handleResponse = response => {
    $scope.status = response.status;
    $scope.isFetching = false;
  };

  $scope.next = (email, password) => {
    $scope.isFetching = true;
    $http
      .post('http://localhost:5000/register', { email, password })
      .then(response => handleResponse(response))
      .catch(response => handleResponse(response));
  };
```

**UPD**

I also tried to add before each `$httpBackend.flush()` this one (like here [Angularjs testing (Jasmine) - $http returning 'No pending request to flush'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573817/angularjs-testing-jasmine-http-returning-no-pending-request-to-flush)):

```
if(!$rootScope.$$phase) {
    $rootScope.$apply();
}
```

But anyway, nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call $httpBackend.flush() after controller creation here:

```
it('should successfully register user', () => {
  const controller = createController();
  $httpBackend.flush(); //<-- this is not necessary if controller creation doesn't involve $http calls
  $httpBackend.expectPOST('http://loalhost:5000/register').respond();
  $scope.next('hello@gmail.com', '123456');
  $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Should be like this:

```
it('should successfully register user', () => {
  const controller = createController();
  $httpBackend.expectPOST('http://loalhost:5000/register').respond();
  $scope.next('hello@gmail.com', '123456');
  $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Comment: Oh my god. I spent about 2 hours for this problem. Thank you so much!